# What is the meaning of "read of"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, conjunctions

I saw this phrase in a sentence. Here it is:

He **read of** the room that was prepared at the palace at Rheims for the use of Queen.

What does it mean?

Comment: Read about the room.

Comment: It's very confusing, as "read of the room" would normally mean ones quick assessment of the room, or, more likely, it's occupants, often immediately upon entering.  But then the likely phrasing would be "His read of the room was that..."  (It doesn't help that "read" and "read" look remarkably similar.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it means that the person read somewhere about the room, like when someone says 'Do you know MJ' and someone else says 'I've heard of him'. I hope I helped. :)